# How to intentionally throw an error in injected code with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, onerror

I have a page with custom `window.addEventListener("error", ...)` logic. I'd like to test that it works, and the only real way to do so is to throw an error.

I tried this:

```
await browser.executeScript("throw new Error();");
```

...but Selenium itself saw the error and considered it an exception. Fine.

```
JavascriptError: Error

  at Object.throwDecodedError (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
  at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:542:13)
  at Executor.execute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
```

Next, tried doing that asynchronously:

```
await browser.executeScript(() => {
    setTimeout(() => { throw new Error(); }, 1);
});
```

...but the page itself didn't notice the error (and yes, I've validated that throwing one in the dev tools triggers the expected handling).

Next, I tried using an async script that schedules an error and then the callback:

```
await browser.executeAsyncScript((callback) => {
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            setTimeout(callback, 1);

            throw new Error();
        },
        1);
});
```

...but the page itself still didn't notice the error.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: throw new Error(); is this the part of calling Javascript method ? .executeScript is looking for Javascript object to by pass on page. You can check it in console window, whether it works there.

Comment: @IshitaShah those code snippets are being run in test files that have a reference to a Selenium `browser` object. In this case, they're in `MyTests.test.js` being run by Node. The goal is to simulate the page having an error thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily simulate that using below script

```
var errorElem = document.createElement("script");
errorElem.textContent = 'throw new Error("simulated error");'
document.body.append(errorElem);
```

This should be able to simulate the event